# Accessing Sharepoint Online lists using Silverlight 5?

Tags: sharepoint-online, silverlight

I'm developing an application using Silverlight 5, Visual Studio 2010 and VB.Net.

I've reached the stage where I have a requirement to read and write information to a Sharepoint Online list, but I'm really struggling to get my head round how I should do this.

There seem to be at couple least a couple of methods:

1. Using Lists.asmx - I have added this as a Service Reference, but it doesn't seems to have made available some methods (?) I would expect to see. i.e. intellisense sees lots of GetListItems* methods, but not plain old GetList. Where am I going wrong?
2. Alternatively, I think I can install the Silverlight Client Object for Sharepoint 2010 and use this? But again I'm not really sure where to start.

Can anybody advise me as to which way I should be leaning, and perhaps give me pointers to start me off.

Thanks,

JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first you need to configure SharePoint Foundation 2010 for your development machine so you can have the Silverlight 5 SharePoint Client Object Model you can find that here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Next after you have completed that use the below link on how to use the Silverlight OM.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538971.aspx

Below is sample code

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Net
     Imports System.Windows
    Imports System.Windows.Controls
    Imports System.Windows.Documents
    Imports System.Windows.Input
    Imports System.Windows.Media
    Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
    Imports System.Windows.Shapes
    Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

    Namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
Partial Public Class MainPage
    Inherits UserControl
    Private oWebsite As Web
    Private collList As ListCollection
    Private listInfo As IEnumerable(Of List)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim clientContext As ClientContext = ClientContext.Current
        oWebsite = clientContext.Web
        Dim collList As ListCollection = oWebsite.Lists

        clientContext.Load(oWebsite, Function(website) website.Title)

        listInfo = clientContext.LoadQuery(collList.Include(Function(list) list.Title, Function(list) list.Fields.Include(Function(field) field.Title).Where(Function(field) field.Required = True AndAlso field.Hidden <> True)))

        clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(AddressOf onQuerySucceeded, AddressOf onQueryFailed)
    End Sub

    Private Sub onQuerySucceeded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs)
        Dim updateUI As UpdateUIMethod = AddressOf DisplayInfo
        Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateUI)
    End Sub

    Private Sub onQueryFailed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ClientRequestFailedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show = "Request failed. " & args.Message & vbLf & args.StackTrace
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayInfo()
        MyOutput.Text = "Title: " & oWebsite.Title
        collList = oWebsite.Lists

        For Each oList As List In listInfo
            MyOutput.Text += vbLf & vbTab & "List: " & oList.Title

            Dim collField As FieldCollection = oList.Fields
            For Each oField As Field In collField
                MyOutput.Text += vbLf & vbTab & vbTab & "Field: " & oField.Title
            Next oField
        Next oList
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateUIMethod()
End Class
End Namespace
```

EDIT:

One more Important Detail about the ClientContext. If you use ClientContext.Current your silverlight application has to be ran within a silverlight web part to work. To access a specific site instantiate your context like below.

```
     Private ReadOnly Property ClientCtxt As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
    Get
        If clientContext Is Nothing Then
            ' clientContext = New ClientContext("http://1mem8400:25775/FTP/Engineering/NPI")
            clientContext = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.Current
        End If
        If clientContext Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("SharePoint Connection Failed")
        End If
        Return clientContext
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Joseph, thanks for the reply. So this is going with the 2nd method I mentioned, I assume? I already have the Sharepoint Foundation Client Object stuff from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786 so I will try your code.

Comment: Ok that is great look at my edit for the gotcha. I don't think that was specified in the MSDN article.

Comment: Another thing I wouldn't Access the Lists.asmx service that is for older applications. You can use the rest interface if you want to use a different client. But if your using Silverlight nothing can beat the simplicity of the OM Microsoft Created.

Comment: If I'm using the Client Object Model does my Silverlight app need to run with elevated trust? Thanks.

Comment: Nope but you do need a ClientAccessPolicy in the sharepoint IIS website root folder for it to work.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302825/how-can-i-add-a-clientaccesspolicy-xml-file-to-the-sharepoint-2010-root-folder

Comment: Is that going to be possible with Sharepoint Online? I would assume not?

Comment: Yes it is you will need to implement a feature set to install the clientpolicy automatically. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2011/04/08/deploying-files-to-the-root-of-a-sharepoint-web-application.aspx

Comment: So, I've added the 2 Sharepoint/Silverlight Client Object DLLs as references and tried using the MSDN sample code, and I'm getting 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' accepts this number of arguments.' and 'Type:Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated' is not defined in App.g.i.vb and Mainpage.g.i.vb. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I can't say until I see the code it looks like you are calling a method on a control somehow. There isn't a Show method that is used with this model. Also make sure that your syntax is correct. The model uses predicates, actions, and asynchronous calls

Comment: OK. I installed Sharepoint Foundation on my Win 7 dev machine, to allow me to test functionality without wondering if it's Office 365 getting in the way. I had to change the namespace from Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples to 'Finisterre' and adjust the x:class statements in my XAML accordingly, and also the Project, Properties, Silverlight, Start up Project to 'Test3.Finisterre.App'. The code now Builds OK (well other than the Messagebox.Show still which I have commented out). I upload the XAP to my SP Foundation site and it runs, but does nothing when I hit the button. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the action the button is suppose to hit. Also make sure that you click the decrease XAP file size in the project properties so you can ensure that your dependencies are in zip files which should be located along with the XAP files. I hope the MessageBox.Show function is not what the button is suppose to do.

Comment: Bingo! It looks like Microsoft have never run that VB code in their example. They look to have changed the MessageBox.Show line from the C# example and have got the syntax wrong i.e. it should be in brackets rather than have an "=".

Comment: Additionally, I regenerated the event handler code in VB by double clicking my button and sticking the display code into there, and it now works. So I am now managing to read the names etc. of my Sharepoint lists in Silverlight, both on my local SharePoint Foundation server AND in Office 365. Thanks for all your help. Now to try and read/write lines to a specific list.

Comment: Open another question and I will post sample code on how to accomplish that task. Glad you got it. I can help at any time so just hit me up or find me on Facebook

Comment: Open a new question they don't like the long comments. I will help you.